# Select SUM and COUNT on same row on PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, **clients** and **transactions**, I´m trying to show on the same row the SUM and COUNT of all the transactions from the same client, and type of transactions, but I don't know how to group it so it only shows the totals of one client and on the next row the total for another client withouth repeting it. Thank you for your time.

> table **clients**
>
> *id_client  -  client_name*
>
> table **transacctions**
>
> *id_transaction  -  client_id  -  date  -  type  -  amount*

```
   $query = " SELECT * FROM  transacctions, clients
    WHERE (transacctions.date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2') 
    AND transactions.client_id = clients.id_client 
    AND transactions.type = '$type' ; "


     <th>Client Name</th>
     <th>Transaction Type</th>
     <th>Number of Transactions</th>
     <th>total amount</th>


       $output.='<td>'.$row['client_name'].'</td>';
       $output.='<td>'.$row['type'].'</td>';
       $output.='<td>'.$row['SUM(amount)'].'</td>';
       $output.='<td>'.$row['COUNT(amount)'].'</td>';
```

Comment: You have "transactions" spelled wrong in a few places and correct in one place.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the client ID and select the sum of the amount and the count of the transaction ID:

```
$query = " SELECT clients.client_name, transacctions.type
SUM(transacctions.amount) AS sum_amount,
COUNT(transacctions.id_transaction) AS transaction_count
FROM  transacctions, clients
WHERE (transacctions.date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2') 
AND transactions.client_id = clients.id_client 
AND transactions.type = '$type' 
GROUP BY clients.id_client; "
```

Alternatively, it is recommended to use joins. This will give you the same results:

```
$query = " SELECT clients.client_name, transacctions.type
SUM(transacctions.amount) AS sum_amount,
COUNT(transacctions.id_transaction) AS transaction_count
FROM  clients
INNER JOIN transacctions ON transactions.client_id = clients.id_client 
WHERE (transacctions.date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2') 
AND transactions.type = '$type' 
GROUP BY clients.id_client; "
```

And if you want to see all clients, including the ones who don't have transactions, then change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`:

```
$query = " SELECT clients.client_name, transacctions.type
SUM(transacctions.amount) AS sum_amount,
COUNT(transacctions.id_transaction) AS transaction_count
FROM  clients
LEFT JOIN transacctions ON transactions.client_id = clients.id_client 
WHERE (transacctions.date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2') 
AND transactions.type = '$type' 
GROUP BY clients.id_client; "
```

Note: I didn't fix the misspelling of "transaction" in your query, because I was not sure if it was a typo or your table actually has that name.

Comment: Thanks, it does bring the SUM and COUNT, but only those values, do you know how to bring the "client_name" and transaction "type" on the same row also?.

Comment: Just add them to the `SELECT`. See my updated answer.